# Grounding and Ground Pour

Tags: pcb, audio, grounding

I’m trying to build my first audio amplifier and need some help and advice on this topic.

It will be a simple 100 W audio amplifier, powered by +35 VDC and -35 VDC. There will be local power decoupling capacitors with 470 uF + 1 uF + 0.1 uF each rail.

Since I’m using mostly THT components, I am able to have all traces (+/-VDC, 0 V, signal and signal ground) all on one single layer. But since the charges for one- or two-layer PCBs are the same, I want to make the best use of both layers.

My few thoughts are:

1. All power and signal traces on the top layer, and one big copper pour (without any trace) at the bottom layer where the signal star grounding point on top layer is connected to it through a HBR, and all 0 V connects directly to the bottom copper pour as well. There will of course be a 0 V/ground out point.
2. Same as (1) above, but put the signal ground traces and signal star grounding point on bottom layer, then connect the signal star grounding point to the copper pour though a HBR which connect to the 0 V/ground out. All 0 V connects directly to the copper pour without any trace.
3. Same as (2) above, but each 0 V will have a trace to the 0 V/ground out point, while the copper pour on the remaining space will also connect to the 0 V/ground out. Meaning there will be signal ground and 0 V traces on the bottom layer connecting to the 0 V/ground out point, and the copper pour on the remaining space will also have a connection to the 0 V/ground out point.

Which option is better? Or are there better options I did not think of?

Also, I don’t intend to do any copper pour on the top layer, but is there any merit doing so?